# amdgpu: [powerplay] #012 failed to send message 282 ret is 65535

Tags: drivers

when I use two displays(HDMI+DVI) in rx550.and the linux kernel is 4.19.
the rx550 is not working sometime.
and the messages is followed:
last message was failed ret is 65535
amdgpu: [powerplay] #012 failed to send message 282 ret is 65535

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.   *You've not said what OS/release you're using, but 4.19 is **not** a supported Ubuntu kernel*